# Why can't blender simply crop a UW image?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, uv-image-editor

I don't think I'll ever understand why there isn't a very simple option for this, but maybe there's a complicated one?

The image I opened has an extra white border around it. I would expect that blender has a way to very easily trim that border, but I don't see any kind of editing option like that in the UV options. Is there at least some kind of way blender can do it? I want to scale the image so it tiles and looks tighter, but the tiling includes that unwanted white border?

Comment: You could do it with the compositor inside blender. But that would make little sense. I would do it in a program that is specialised in image editing such as photoshop.

Comment: The simple answer to your first question is that Blender is a 3D creation suite and not an image manipulation tool. There are tons of the latter on the market, even [FLOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software#FLOSS) like Gimp and Krita. All of them do the job of image manipulation better than Blender's Image Editor does. No need to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: Well we're at it, let's let's just for everyone to never use blender at all since there's "already" other 3D software on the market.

Comment: It will be a nice feature. But unfortunately Blender has limit resources to develop the whole program. The job you described will likely being supported by an **custom addon**.

Comment: maybe you should create an addon to crop pictures in Blender